# whats the recommended approach for input validation in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which works pretty well from the server side:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper.js';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import { Input } from 'antd';
import Form from '../../components/uielements/form';
import Checkbox from '../../components/uielements/checkbox';
import Button from '../../components/uielements/button';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {TenantId: '', TenantUrl: '', CertificatePassword: '' };
    this.handleChangeTenantUrl = this.handleChangeTenantUrl.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeCertificatePassword = this.handleChangeCertificatePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantId= this.handleChangeTenantId.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  };


  handleChangeTenantUrl(event){
    this.setState({TenantUrl: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeCertificatePassword(event){
    this.setState({CertificatePassword: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantId(event){
    this.setState({TenantId: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = new FormData();
    //Append files to form data
    data.append("model", JSON.stringify({ "TenantId": this.state.TenantId, "TenantUrl": this.state.TenantUrl, "CertificatePassword": this.state.CertificatePassword }));
    //data.append("model", {"TenantId": this.state.TenantId, "TenantUrl": this.state.TenantUrl, "TenantPassword": this.state.TenantPassword });

    let files = this.state.selectedFiles;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      data.append("file", files[i], files[i].name);
    }

    const options = {
      method: 'put',
      body: data,
      config: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    };

    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          this.setState({ data: responseJson });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  upload(e){
    let files = e.target.files;
    this.setState({ 'selectedFiles': files });
}

  render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 6 },
      },
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 14 },
      },
    };
    const tailFormItemLayout = {
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: {
          span: 24,
          offset: 0,
        },
        sm: {
          span: 14,
          offset: 6,
        },
      },
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <LayoutWrapper>
        <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
        <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
          <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
            <Box
              title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
              subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
            >
              <ContentHolder>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                  TenantId:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantId} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantId} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantUrl:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantUrl} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantUrl} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantPassword:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.CertificatePassword} onChange={this.handleChangeCertificatePassword} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Certificate:
                  <input onChange = { e => this.upload(e) } type = "file" id = "files" ref = { file => this.fileUpload } />
                </label>             
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
              </ContentHolder>
            </Box>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </LayoutWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However i need the id to be required and a guid format, the other 2 fields must be mandatory.

Whats the recommended way in reactjs?

Comment: Even though you're not using redux, check out [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/submitvalidation/)

Comment: [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) is a nice alternative as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async, and for validation input types is best use callback, what is fired when state is updated:

```
handleChangeTenantId(event) {
    this.setState({ TenantId: event.target.value }, () => {
      const valid = validate(this.state.TenantId)
      if (!valid) {
        this.setState({ TenantId: null })
      }
    });
  }
```

or

```
handleChangeTenantId(event) {
  const TenantId = event.target.value;
  const valid = validate(TenantId);
  if (valid) {
    this.setState({ TenantId })
  }
}
```

Comment: Validating after the state is updated is not correct

Comment: why? in some scenarios is correct.